# Цикл JavaScript для заполнения таблицы полученными данными

Tags: javascript, html, циклы, while

Есть таблица,которая заполняется после того как пользователь вводит данные и нажимает кнопку "Add Log Time".Таблица должна заполняться от ранней к поздней записи и делать это в цикле.

У меня проблема заключается в том,что данные заменяют друг друга,а не идут по порядку.А так же при добавление новой строки,она дублирует первую.

Помогите пожалуйста решить две эти проблемы
Спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Tracker+</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var activate;
    var startButton;

    function trim(string) { return string.replace (/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, ''); }
    var init=0;
    var startDate;
    var clocktimer;


    function clearFields() {
        activate = false;
        clearTimeout(clocktimer);
        startDate = undefined;
        startButton.value = "Start";
        document.clockform.clock.value='00:00:00.00';
        document.clockform.label.value='';
        document.clockform.description.value='';
        document.clockform.datetimepicker2.value='';
    }


    function clearALL() {
        clearFields();
        document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML = '';
    }

    function executeTimer()  {
        var thisDate = new Date();
        var t = thisDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var ms = t%1000; t-=ms; ms=Math.floor(ms/10);
        t = Math.floor (t/1000);
        var s = t%60; t-=s;
        t = Math.floor (t/60);
        var m = t%60; t-=m;
        t = Math.floor (t/60);
        var h = t%60;
        if (h<10) h='0'+h;
        if (m<10) m='0'+m;
        if (s<10) s='0'+s;
        if (ms<10) ms='0'+ms;
        document.clockform.clock.value = h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.' + ms;
        clocktimer = setTimeout("executeTimer()",10);
    }


    function startTIME() {
        if(!activate){
            startButton.value = "Pause";
            activate = !activate;
            if(startDate == undefined) startDate = new Date();
            executeTimer();
            return;
        }
        else {
            startButton.value = "Start";
            activate = !activate;
            clearTimeout(clocktimer);
            return;
        }
    }

    function stopALL(){
        clearTimeout(clocktimer);
        init=0;
    }

    function addLogTime(){
        var str = trim(document.clockform.label.value);
        var x = trim(document.clockform.clock.value);
        var y = trim(document.clockform.datetimepicker2.value);
        var z = trim(document.clockform.description.value);
        
        document.getElementById('td2').innerHTML = (str==''?'':str)
        document.getElementById('td3').innerHTML = (x==''?'':x)
        document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML = (y==''?'':y)
        document.getElementById('td4').innerHTML = (z==''?'':z)
        document.getElementById('marker').innerHTML;

        clearFields();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        startButton = document.getElementsByName("starter")[0];
        document.clockform.clock.value='00:00:00.00';
        activate = false;
    }

    function deleteRow(row) {
        var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
    }

    function insRow() {
        var x = document.getElementById('POITable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;


        new_row.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
            .forEach(function (item) {
                item.value = "";
            });


        x.appendChild(new_row);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
    });


</script>
<noscript><p>Извините, для работы приложения нужен включённый JavaScript</p></noscript>

<form name="clockform" style="background: #F5F5F5">
    <p>
    <h3>Time Tracker</h3>
    <input name="add log time" type="button" value="Add Log Time" style="background:#CD5C5C" onclick="addLogTime()">
    <input name="reset" type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearALL()">
    </br>
    </br>
    Time spent:
    <input name="clock" size="12" maxlength="12" value="00:00:00.00">
    <input name="starter" type="button" value="Start" onclick="startTIME()">
    <input name="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopALL()">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Name:
    <input name="label" size="12" maxlength="30" value="">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Work description:
    <input  name="description" size="24" value="">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Start Date:
    <div class='input-group date; col-xs-2' id='datetimepicker2' style="right:-910px;top:-30px" >
        <input type='text' name="datetimepicker2" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
    </div>
    </p><p id="marker">
</p>
</form>
<br>
<h3>Time Log</h3>
<div id="POItablediv">
    <table id="POITable" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;width: 700px;">
        <tr style="background:#C0C0C0;font-weight: bold">
            <td>Start Date</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Spent time</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td style="width: 25px"></td>
            <td style="width: 25px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td id="td2"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td id="td3"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td style="word-wrap:break-word" id="td4"><input type="text"/></td>
            <td style="width: 25px"><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td style="width: 25px"><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="+" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы сами руками заменяете существующую строчку новым данными, а новые  строчки ( элементы ) не добавляете

Comment: а почему вы удаляете предыдущие вопросы?)